# How to prevent default parameter from overwriting an assigned value?

Tags: c#, methods, parameter-passing

Here is my code: A method to change parts of a PC.

```
internal void ModifyPC(double CPU_Clockspeed = 0, int RAM = 0, int storage = 0, int graphicsMemory = 0)
{
    this.CPU_Clockspeed = CPU_Clockspeed;
    this.RAM_capacity = RAM;
    this.storage = storage;
    this.graphicsCardCapacity = graphicsMemory;
}
```

How do i change only a single variable value without the default values overwriting the others?

E.g i have created a PC with 4.0 Ghz CPU, 16GB RAM, 250GB storage and 8GB GraphicsCard. `Desktop PC = new Desktop(4.0, 16, 250, 8);`

If i try to change, for example, CPU to 4.5 Ghz: `PC.ModifyPC(CPU_Clockspeed: 4.5);`, this will overwrite all other attributes to 0.

Comment: then you need to default all to nullable and only assign a value if not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default all to `Nullable<>` and only assign a value if not null

```
internal void ModifyPC(
    double? CPU_Clockspeed = null, int? RAM = null, int? storage = null, int? graphicsMemory = null)
{
    this.CPU_Clockspeed = CPU_Clockspeed.GetValueOrDefault(this.CPU_Clockspeed);
    this.RAM_capacity = RAM.GetValueOrDefault(this.RAM_capacity);
    this.storage = storage.GetValueOrDefault(this.storage);
    this.graphicsCardCapacity = graphicsMemory.GetValueOrDefault(this.graphicsCardCapacit);
}
```

Now only the parameters with passed value will be set

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot have negative values for any of those parameters, in theory, you can use -1 instead of null. Then you can apply the following logic to your function.

```
internal void ModifyPC(double CPU_Clockspeed = -1, int RAM = -1, int storage = -1, int graphicsMemory = -1)
{
   if (CPU_Clockspeed != -1) this.CPU_Clockspeed = CPU_Clockspeed;
   if (RAM != -1) this.RAM_capacity = RAM;
   if (storage != -1) this.storage = storage;
   if (graphicsMemory != -1) this.graphicsCardCapacity = graphicsMemory;
}
```

Comment: `Int32.MinValue` is a safer bet than -1 (at the cost of being more verbose).

Comment: Ya, I do like that better than -1, because then everything is constants. And this seems cleaner than the accepted answer with all the nulls.